# Why is "She requested that he raise his hand" the correct sentence, not "She requested that he had raised his hand"?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

I'm reading about the subjunctive mood and i have trouble grasping the following sentence from [https://data.grammarbook.com/blog](https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/effective-writing/subjunctive-mode-and-some-confusing-words/).

```
Examples:
She requested that he raise his hand.
```

I have understood that with verbs besides were, past perfect tense should be used with the subjunctive mood. Is "raise" really past perfect or am i missing something?

Thank you

Comment: [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) will be much more helpful than us in this regard.

Comment: About the question in the title: the ‘*had raised*’ version is grammatical, but requesting that the past be changed is typically an exercise in futility.

Comment: Good point. This raised another question. If i swap out the verb 'requested' for the verb 'hoped',  is the 'raise' version still correct?

Comment: Why, please? What difference did you think that would make? You should have posted explanations of your thoughts about the first Question and don't you think leaving them out again is more than twice as remiss?